# Когда пишутся слитно слова нерусский, немосковский, немосквич  и др.?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Насколько ЧЕТКИМИ являются правила  выбора слитной или раздельной формы написания НЕ в подобных словах (немосковский, нерусский, нездешний, неженский, немужской, неспециалист, нелитератор)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для меня - вполне чёткие:

Слитное написание этих слов возможно только в том случае, если они приобретают качественное значение, например:неженская логика – это строгая, системная логика, которая обычно несвойственна женщинам; немосквич – человек, который мыслит и ведет себя иначе, по сравнению с коренными москвичами. Обычно эта группа слова употребляются в синтаксических конструкциях со слитным написанием, где они играют роль определения, подлежащего или дополнения, например: рассуждать с неженской логикой.

Если такого качественного значения в данном тексте нет, то эти слова пишутся раздельно с частицей НЕ, при этом они, как правило, используются в отрицательных конструкциях, например: это не женская работа (НЕ относится к словосочетанию).

немужской (слабый) характер,неженский (сильный) ум-прил. с приставкой НЕ обозначают качеств. признак. Немужской поступок. Немужские замашки какие-то. Но ум у нее – сильный, как говорится «неженский».
это не женская работа   - НЕ относится к словосочетанию 
Рубить дрова – не женская работа.
логика не мужская, а женская-противопоставление 
Это интуитивная логика – не мужская, а женская.

У него немосковский взгляд на Москву. Немосквичу(чужому, далёкому по духу)трудно понять это. 
совсем не московская погода-усиление отрицания
На Волхонке – совсем не московский пейзаж: гигантская лужа глубиной больше метра. 
он не москвич (живет не в Москве)отрицание: не является москвичом 
Каждый третий покупатель квартир в Москве – не москвич.

его признали все грамотные люди века – и литераторы, и нелитераторы-  
существительное имеет качественное значение 
Но и для нелитератора чтение поэзии – это воспитание тонкости восприятия жизни.
я не литератор и не поэт-отрицание, усиление отрицания
Ты знаешь, что я отнюдь не литератор.

нездешняя (чужая) красота,нездешние повадки - прилагательное обозначает качественный признак.Блистать нездешней красотой. Сидел он, не смыкая очи, нездешней мукою томим. 
он не здешний   - отрицание: не является здешним  
Думаю, они не здешние.

нерусский менталитет, внешность -качественный признак 
Учебники для нерусских школ. 
он не русский -отрицание  
Не русский я, но россиянин.

http://pochit.ru/filosofiya/1926/index.html?page=3

Comment: Очень даже согласна. Приставка НЕ придает противоположное значение, частица НЕ отрицает значение, выраженное существительным или прилагательным. То или иное написание помогает понять мысль автора.